# Only execute once for every ID in array list

Tags: java

I'm getting results from a PHP, and parse them to a String array
ParseResults[0] is the ID returned from the database.

What I'm trying to do, is make a message box, which is only shown once (until the application is restarted of course).

My code looks something like this, but I can't figure out what stops it from working properly.

```
public void ShowNotification() {
    try {

        ArrayList<String> SearchGNArray = OverblikIntetSvar(Main.BrugerID);
        // SearchGNArray = Gets undecoded rows of information from DB
        for(int i=0; i<SearchGNArray.size(); i++){

            String[] ParseTilArray = ParseResultater(SearchGNArray.get(i));
            // ParseToArray = Parse results and decode to useable results
            // ParseToArray[0] = the index containing the ID we'd like 
            // to keep track of, if it already had shown a popup about it

            if (SearchPopUpArray.size() == 0) {
                // No ID's yet in SearchPopUpArray
                // SearchPopUpArray = Where we'd like to store our already shown ID's
                SearchPopUpArray.add(ParseTilArray[0]);

                // Create Messagebox

            }

            boolean match = false ;
            for(int ii=0; ii<SearchPopUpArray.size(); ii++){

                try {
                    match = SearchPopUpArray.get(ii).equals(ParseTilArray[0]);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                if(match){
                    // There is a match
                    break; // Break to not create a popup

                } else {

                    // No match in MatchPopUpArray
                    SearchPopUpArray.add(ParseTilArray[0]);

                    // Create a Messagebox

                }
            }



         }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

As of now I have 2 rows, so there should be two ID's. There's 101 and 102. It shows 102 once, and then it just keeps creating messageboxes about 101.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing the right variable in the second for-loop:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii <SearchPopUpArray.size();i++){
                                       /*   ^
                                            |
                                          should be ii++
                                       */
}
```

It might be help to use more descriptive variable name like `indexGN` and `indexPopup` instead to avoid this sort of issue

Comment: It's now incremented with ii++, but i'm getting a dead code warning... So it's only running through the loop once, I guess?

Comment: What part of the code is dead according to the warning ?

Comment: The for loop containing ii++

if i try to System.out.println(ii) after match = ...
I get the value (0) back - so it's never incremented

Comment: Isn't it because `match == true` on the 1st iteration? Your code will break out of the loop in this case, so `ii` will never be incremented.

Comment: You're right! I've removed break now, and it is incrementing as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted the second for loop:

```
         for(int ii=0; ii<SearchPopUpArray.size(); ii++){

            try {
                match = SearchPopUpArray.get(ii).equals(ParseTilArray[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            if(match){
                // There is a match

            } else {

                // No match in MatchPopUpArray
                SearchPopUpArray.add(ParseTilArray[0]);

                // Create a Messagebox

            }
        }
```

And replaced with

```
            if (SearchPopUpArray.contains(ParseTilArray[0])) {
                // Match
            } else {
                // No match i MatchPopUpArray
                SearchPopUpArray.add(ParseTilArray[0]);

                // Create a Messagebox
            }
```

Much more simple.